# SdkUtility.LaunchSignInPage not redirecting to ebay sign in page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-4.5

.Net 4.5 , MVC 5 , IIS 8

```
SdkUtility.LaunchSignInPage(apiContext, _sessionID);
```

From my application (in VS 2013) I can easily access to the sign in page. But problem occurs when I published it in IIS. firstly it shows error like access denied.

I have searched and in IIS, ApplicationIdentity pool, I gave **NETWORK_SERVICE** and gave Network Service full authentication to read or read & execute...

Error does not show up any more. but the sign in page does not appear.

**EDIT 1: **

**Using ASP .Net MVC 5, IIS 8.0.0.9, eBaySdk**

While I try to get token via SDK call, this error occurs. Of course after hosting. but  in visual studio, it works fine. What I think is, I have to set certain level of permission to allow users to use sdk or something like that. Here is the full error trace.

**Access is denied**

**Description**:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. 
>       Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
>          System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo) +773
>          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +123
>          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +49
>          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName) +31
>          eBay.Service.Util.SdkUtility.LaunchSignInPage(ApiContext Context, String SessionID) +671
>          VialinkerApps.App_Start.eBayApi.GetToken(UrlHelper url) +523
>          VialinkerApps.Controllers.SettingsController.AcceBay(eBaySetting
>   eBaySetting) +16
>          lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
>          System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>          System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary2 parameters) +156
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2
>   parameters) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
>
> ```
>     System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
> ```
>
> result) +9
>              System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9651796
>              System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Can you give us some background information? What does appear? Resulting DOM code? Any exceptions?

Comment: @abdur Rahim Can you provide morecode?and error screen shotts

Comment: @D.R. Here are the exception trace from IIS

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj Here are the exception trace from IIS

Comment: What operating system are you running your IIS on?

Comment: Oh, and the NETWORK_SERVICE user has only limited access rights on the local system - try executing the AppPool as LocalService instead. Also give exeuction privileges to IUSR.

Comment: @D.R. I am checking on it. still no progress. getting some other errors. I will let you know asap.

Comment: Instead of NETWORK_SERVICE, try giving IIS_USRS (a new group introduced after IIS7), all permissions you need.

Comment: Look At this ..it will helpfull to you..http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand by reading the Stack Trace you can see it's trying to do a System.Diagnostics.Process.Start. This sounds pretty wierd to me trying to "redirect" on a webserver (IIS).

And should give you errors as your literally trying to start an executable in you IIS process.

This behaviour seems more likely if you run it in a Desktop application, to "start" your default browser with an URL.

Would also explain why it seems to be working locally in Visual Studio.

I'd check any documentation if it's suposed to be used from an IIS/ASP.NET application.

Comment: The function LaunchSignInPage does not seem to be designed for use in an MVC / ASP.NET application, if it calls Process.Start. More likely designed for implementing Oauth in an Desktop application.

Comment: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Basics/Tokens-MultipleUsers.html _____ in this link, they describe, how to create a sign in url and redirect to it and after accepting consent form it will redirect to my application. I tried that way before, but after accepting consent form when ebay returns the user to my application, then the previous apicontext & session id is gone. which I need to fetch token. Another point is, I am succesfully using this LaunchSignIn method from VS as a MVC web application.

Comment: When working in VS, the internal dev server has more rights to do things than you do when you're on an actuall IIS. Most probably that is what you are experiencing. As I said, reading the stack trace this is my best guess. I can also understand if it works locally. I am no ebay guru just sharing my thoughts :). An approach with Process.Start is not good in a hosted environment.